# spring bean startup/shutdown order configuration (start h2 db as server)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I'd like to create configuration/bean to automatically start H2DB in my development profile. I'd like to have it running as a tcp server. It's needed to be started before any DataSource configuration. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Wha have I done is

```
@Profile("h2")
@Component
public class H2DbServerConfiguration implements SmartLifecycle {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(H2DbServerConfiguration.class);

    private Server server;

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable callback) {
        stop();
        new Thread(callback).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        logger.debug("############################################");
        logger.debug("############################################");
        logger.debug("STARTING SERVER");
        logger.debug("############################################");
        logger.debug("############################################");
        try {
            server = Server.createTcpServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082").start();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to start H2 server", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        logger.debug("############################################");
        logger.debug("############################################");
        logger.debug("STOPPING SERVER");
        logger.debug("############################################");
        logger.debug("############################################");
        if (server != null)
            if (server.isRunning(true))
                server.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return server != null ? server.isRunning(true) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but this isn't an option for me because component is created after datasource (I have liquibase setup so it's too late) and Phase is still the same that means FIFO order and I'd like to be FILO.

Answer (score 0):

Create your server as a bean :

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")     
    Server h2Server() throws Exception {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp","-tcpAllowOthers","-tcpPort","9192");
    }
```

Now you can configure spring to create other beans (e.g the datasource)
after the bean h2Server using @DependsOn

```
@DependsOn("h2Server")
@Bean 
DataSource dataSource(){
...
}
```

**Hi, what about using spring boot? It has automatically configured datasource so I don't want to reconfigure it.**

You are right, to use the above approach you have to create your own datasource in order to annotate it with @DependsOn .

But it looks like this is not really necessary.
In one of my projects I am creating the h2Server as a bean as described.
I use the datasource created by spring, so without any @DependsOn.
It works perfectly. Just give it a try.

Your solution with SmartLifecycle does not work, because it creates the server on ApplicationContext refresh, which happens after all beans (including the datasource ) were created.

Comment: Hi, what about using spring boot? It has automatically configured datasource so I don't want to reconfigure it.

Answer (score 0):

Mix @Profile and @Component seams to me a bad idea. Profiles are designed to work with Configuration ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-java))

Do you really need profile? In my opinion it makes sense if you have several possible configurations, one based on H2, and if you want be able to switch between these configurations (typically at start time by setting a properties...)

Manage the H2 server with a bean ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-nature)) seams correct to me (as suggested by Stefen). Maybe you will prefer annotations... If you want a spring profile, then you will need a Configuration object too. It will simply load the H2 server bean (in my opinion it's better to manage the H2 server lifecycle with a bean than with a context/config).